# Showing the email of the person to whom I sent a comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I use the following code to show the email of the person to whom I sent a comment.

Controller:

```rb
@to_user = User.where(id: @comment.to_id)
```

View:

```rb
<%= @to_user.email  %>
```

Only it generates an error: `` undefined method `email' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007feb364b8218> ``

Showing "from" user works well:

```rb
<%= @comment.user.email %>
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.where`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where) returns an ActiveRecord_Relation, which you can think of like an array of records (actually, the records aren't loaded yet, but as soon as you call a method like `.each` or `.to_a` it evaluates the query and turns it into an array).

What you are looking for is either

- [`.find`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/find) (`User.find(@comment.to_id)`) - this will raise an error if the user is not found
- [`.find_by`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/find_by) (`User.find_by(id: @comment.to_id)`) - this will return nil if the user is not found

You could also just call `.first` on the `.where` result - as often is the case in Ruby/Rails, there are many ways to do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

To [retrieve a single object](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-a-single-object), you use [`find`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find):

```
@to_user = User.find(@comment.to_id)
```

But it's more idiomatic to define a [`belongs_to` association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association) in your `Comment` model, e.g.:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :to_user, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'to_id'
  # ...
end
```

This allows you to simply write:

```
<%= @comment.to_user.email %>
```

To avoid confusion, you might want to rename the exising `user` to `from_user`. Or maybe use more descriptive names like `sender` and `receiver`.

And if you do so, it would be a good idea to also rename the columns from `user_id` and `to_id` to `from_user_id` and `to_user_id` (or `sender_id` and `receiver_id`).

Comment: Thank you - the other answer came earlier, so I chose that. I've upvoted your answer instead.